# AngularJS re-rendering in ng-repeat inner working

Tags: angularjs

The following code contain a input box, a radio button and a button.

When the button is clicked, it will generate one more inputbox and radio button. All the radio button are under the same name.

```
  <ul ng-repeat="i in addQuestion.loop(addQuestion.numOfChoice) track by $index">
    <li>
        answers:<input type="text"/>
        correct:<input type="radio" name="correctChoice" value ={{$index}}/>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-Click="addQuestion.numOfChoice = addQuestion.numOfChoice + 1">add more choices</button><br/><br/>
```

//controller:

```
$scope.addQuestion = {
  numOfChoice: 1,
  loop: function(num){
    return new Array(num);
  }
}
```

My question is while I successfully made this work the way I wanted. 
I have no idea how the 'magic' work on the re-rendering whenever a numOfChoice get incremented.

Two questions:

1. In the ng-repeat it calls the function `loop` that takes in a parameter: how does the change of the argument trigger a re-render, causing the loop to run again. I would understand if it is a variable.
2. Whenever I click "add more", it will render one more inputbox and radio button, I don't understand how the states of the previous rendered inputbox/box stay there. In something like reactJS, it will re-render the whole thing, and all the state is lost unless I store it somewhere. How does it store all the state while re-rending the whole ng-repeat loop. Or does it not re-run the ng-repeat but do something else? does it have something to do with the index?

Hope I was clear on my question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The function loop returns a new object which ngRepeat was tracking. So when the value of ng-repeat loop variable changes, it triggers the new rendering.
2. ngRepeat keeps track of all items in the collection and their corresponding DOM elements. So if the item already exists for example, it will not re-render.